# Can't import FirebaseMessaging in objective-c AppDelegate.h

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, push-notification, firebase-authentication

When ever i write **@import FirebaseMessaging;** is says -

*Module 'FirebaseMessaging' not found*

**What i did** - At first i install the pods with only *Firebase/Core* but after that i realised *Firebase/Messaging* is also necessary.
Then i wrote **pod 'Firebase/Messaging'** in the pod file and install the pods again.

The pod folder contains the folder as Firebase Messaging but when i import it it says no module found.[image: Here is the screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import `FirebaseMessaging` separately in the latest Firebase SDK according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client):

> You'll need to add Firebase initialization code to your application. Import the Firebase module and configure a shared instance as shown:
>
> 1. Import the Firebase module in your UIApplicationDelegate:

```
@import Firebase;
```

> 2. Configure a FirebaseApp shared instance, typically in your application's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
// Use Firebase library to configure APIs
[FIRApp configure];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was really worried about that.

Comment: Also, while not needed, the @import FirebaseMessaging will work after building. The Xcode editor doesn't recognize CocoaPods modules until after an initial build.